# How to sort the array and display it to the console using ForEach and Filter?

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach, frontend

How to sort the array and display it to the console using ForEach and Filter, you first need to display all the last names, after that, the last names with the letter "F"? What am I doing wrong?
'use strict';
// https://reqres.in/api/users

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=12')
    .then((response) => {
       return  response.json();
    })
    .then((body) => {
        body?.data.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item.last_name);
        })
        const filtered = body?.data.filter((item) => {
            return item.last_name === 'F';
            console.log(filtered);
        });
    console.log(filtered);
 });
```

Comment: console.log(filtered); is after the return inside the filter block.... it will never be called.

Comment: After placing a call elsewhere, nothing happens(

Comment: Your filter is never going to return anything unless the person's name is "F" You are not looking at the first letter in the name, you are comparing "F" to the whole name

Comment: The problem is that first you need to display all the surnames, and then display only the surnames starting with the letter "F", but for some reason this does not work (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking the first letter of the last name

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=12')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((body) => {
    const filtered = body?.data.filter((item) => {
      return item.last_name[0] === 'F';
    });
    console.log(filtered);
  });
```

Comment: The problem is that first you need to display all the surnames, and then display only the surnames starting with the letter "F", but for some reason this does not work (

Comment: @DenisPrudnikov I gave you info on why your code was not returning anything in the console. I fixed the filter code in the above to show why it was not filtering out the correctly. You can put back in your forEach loop.

Comment: Can you show how to revert to a forEach loop?

Comment: EXACTLY how you did it in your code.